# How do i sort an array of a class alphabetically

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to sort this by name alphabetically how would i do this ?

```
it[i].actor,
it[i].name,
it[i].house,
it[i].image
```

Answer (score 0):

```
it.sortBy { item -> item.name }
```

Example:
https://pl.kotl.in/3Wf37ovnY